# Can't plot data from dictionary

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have dictionary *dates_temperatures* and i'm trying to plot it using matplotlib but it doesn't work.

```
def graph_plotting(dates_temperatures): #setting graph
plt.plot(dates_temperatures.keys(), dates_temperatures.values())
plt.set_title('Weather Forecast')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.set_ylabel('Temperature')
plt.set_xlim(xmin=dates_temperatures[0], xmax=dates_temperatures[-1])
plt.legend(loc=(0.65, 0.8))
plt.set_title('Forecast')
plt.yaxis.tick_right()
```

I don't know why but I got

> "AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'plot'"

Please help

Comment: The correct idiom is `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`,  it seems that you used instead `import matplotlib as plt`

Comment: now i got *AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'set_title'*

Comment: You are mixing the stateful API with the OO Api...  `set_title` is a method of an Axes object, not an attribute of the module.  It's `plt.title('...')` — what about stepping through a Matplotlib tutorial?

Comment: Cool, maybe I don't understand something, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you want, using the correct imports and OO interface:

```py
import matlotlib.pyplot as plt

def graph_plotting(dates_temperatures): #setting graph
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(dates_temperatures.keys(), dates_temperatures.values())
    ax.set_title('Weather Forecast')
    ax.legend(loc='upper left')
    ax.set_ylabel('Temperature')
    ax.set_xlim(
        xmin=list(dates_temperatures.keys())[0],
        xmax=list(dates_temperatures.keys())[-1]
    )
    ax.yaxis.tick_right()
```